# Internet Explorer waits to user action - no refresh in the background

Tags: session, internet-explorer, request, single-sign-on, saml

I am facing very interesting issue and I am not sure what can cause this. I am using SSO SAML for authentication to the system and IE11 as the browser to access the application. After some time (e.g. 5 min) the session terminates and it is renewed and it is a background process. Somehow only in IE, the session is not renewed until I maximize the browser and do some user action (after that it works). Other browsers are not affected and everything works in background properly. Do anyone know what can cause the issue in IE that the browser needs to user action?

Comment: Did you find anything in browser console ? If this is application which is not able to  renew the token, it should be specific to either service provider(or the application). AFAIK there are auto submit scripts(JavaScript).

Comment: There is nothing in the browser console. Everything is fine. The application is able to renew token and it requests IdP for new assertion - as expected. But when the browser is minimalized, nothing is happening there and the current time for assertion is postponed to a time when the user does some action in a browser. And this causes the issue that the assertion is not valid. In another browser there is everything fine - so there is no issue in IdP or SP.

Comment: File>Properties will tell you which IE security zone your host(s) is mapped to. IE uses security zones. There is a setting regarding navigation into zones of lower integrity and also for meta-refresh. Other browsers do not use Security zones (granular by-site basis). Use the f12>Console tab, to confirm that your dev environment is not mapped to the Intranet zone and using Compatibility View. Set the IE f12 to record blocked content and security warnings and errors. Advanced tab of Internet Options>check "Always record developer console messages".